# Does the lock on a static synchronized method affect the non-static synchronized methods of it's instances?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Suppose I have 2 methods, one declared as `synchronized` and the other declared as `static synchronized`.
So when a thread acquires the class-level lock, does it acquire the locks on all its instances as well? In other words, if a thread acquires a class-level lock, can another thread acquire an object-level lock on one of its instances simultaneously?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `static synchronized` method will acquire the lock on the `Class` instance for the class. A `synchronized` method will acquire the lock on `this`. When you acquire the class level lock by calling a synchronized static method, the object-level locks are not affected.